# sed: replacing nth word with matched pattern?

Tags: regex, perl, bash, sed, awk

I have a text file with the following characteristics:

1. every line has at least three "words" separated by a space
2. a "word" can be any character or string of characters

I have appended some notes to some of the lines with tentative suggestions for changes to be made to the original words, and now would like to use sed to make those changes for me.  So, to give a clearer picture, my file looks like this:

```
NO NO O
SIGNS NN O      #NNS
GIVEN VBD B-VP  #VBN
AT IN O
THIS NN O       
TIME NN O            ## B-NP
. PER O
...
```

Notes with 1 # are to replace the SECOND word in a line, and notes with 2 #'s are to replace the THIRD word in a line.  Would anybody be able to suggest a way to do this with sed (or awk, or anything else)?  Again to clarify (hopefully), my goal is to get the pattern following the # or ## and replace the nth word of the line with the matched pattern.

Thanks.

Comment: is it possible to make it a rule that your notes have a predetermined amount of spaces after the `#`? Right now you show notes that have both zero and one spaces after the `#`, this makes the code unnecessarily harder to accommodate that. It would make it much easier if your notes have zero spaces after

Comment: also, do you want the notes to be in the output?

Comment: @SiegeX: yes, I should quite easily be able to remove the extra space in "## B-NP" or add a space in "#NNS", as desired.

Comment: @SiegeX: no, I don't want the note in the output -- I do want to keep a marker like "#" a couple of tabs after to designate the lines I've changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work for you:

```
awk '/#/{sub(/# +/,"#");n=gsub(/#/,"",$NF);$(n+1)=$NF;$NF="\t\t#"}1' file
```

#### Explanation

1. `/#/{ ... }`: Search for lines that contain `#` and perform the following steps...
2. `sub(/# +/,"#")`: Remove all spaces between the notes and the `#` if necessary
3. `n=gsub(/#/,"",$NF)`: Remove all `#` from the last field `$NF` and set the number of `#`'s removed to the variable `n`
4. `$(n+1)=$NF`: Set the n+1 field `$(n+1)` to the new last field `$NF` which has all the `#` stripped off
5. `$NF="\t\t#"`: Set the last field `$NF` to two tabs followed by a `#`
6. `1`: Shortcut to tell `awk` to print the altered line
7. `file`: Your input file

#### Example

```
$ awk '/#/{sub(/# +/,"#");n=gsub(/#/,"",$NF);$(n+1)=$NF;$NF="\t\t#"}1' file
NO NO O
SIGNS NNS O             #
GIVEN VBN B-VP          #
AT IN O
THIS NN O
TIME NN B-NP            #
. PER O
...
```

***Note***: If you make it so your notes always following the `#` with zero spaces in between, you can remove the entire `sub(/# +/,"#");` part of the command to make it even shorter

Comment: Thanks.  I'm unfamiliar with awk, so I'll have to do some studying up to understand what's going on here.  I can't really translate your note into a different command, though.  Would it be: awk '/#/{;t=$NF;n=gsub(/#/,"",t);$(n+1)=t}1' notes ??  This looks a little bizarre...

Comment: It would be `/#/{n=gsub(/#/,"",$NF);$(n+1)=$NF;$NF="\t\t#"}1' file`

Comment: I just ran your command on my file and it appears to have worked perfectly.  I can't thank you enough.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
sed 's/\S*\(\s*\S*\s*#\s*\)\([^#]*\)$/\2\1/;s/ *##*.*/\t\t#/' file
NO NO O
SIGNS NNS O             #
GIVEN VBN B-VP          #
AT IN O
THIS NN O       
TIME NN B-NP            #
. PER O
...
```

Comment: yes, this works as well.  I had spent the longest time trying to do this in sed, and the command I came up with was nightmarish.  The interpreter kept telling me that my /1 and /2 identifiers were invalid.

Comment: The trick here is to anchor the regexp to the end of the string (`$`) and use the the extra `#` to pull the back reference one field closer (see `\(\s*\S*\s*#\s*\)`).

Answer (score 0):

Perl can handle this. Though I think I'd prefer to make it a script.

Paste version:

```
perl -lnwe 's/#\K\s+//; my @a=/\S+/g; if (@a>3) { $c = $a[3] =~ tr/#//d; $a[$c] = $a[3]; } print join " ", @a[0..2]' file
```

This version will print to stdout and not change the file. Add `-i.bak`, e.g. `perl -i.bak -lnwe '....'` to do in-place edit, with backup in `file.bak`.

Readable version:

```
$ perl -lnwe '       # -l: handle newlines, -n read file/stdin
    s/#\K\s+//;                    # strip optional spaces
    my @a = /\S+/g;                # extract the data
    if (@a > 3) {                  # when there are replacements..
        my $c = $a[3] =~ tr/#//d;  # count and remove #
        $a[$c] = $a[3];            # set element number $c to element 3
    } print join " ", @a[0..2]     # reassemble and print 3 first elements
' file
```

**Output:**

```
NO NO O
SIGNS NNS O
GIVEN VBN B-VP
AT IN O
THIS NN O
TIME NN B-NP
. PER O
```